# Non-array argument in array_merge()-function

Tags: php, array

I'm building a small plugin, basically with a settings page that holds four text fields and two checkboxes. Everything works fine, including the checkboxes - as long as one or both of them are ticked off. If not, im getting an error message saying:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in ...

That would be the second argument in the *minevalg_hent_innstillinger*-function;

```
function minevalg_hent_innstillinger() {
                $defaults = array(); // define this somewhere; reference it here
                return array_merge( $defaults, get_option( 'minevalg', array() ) );
            }
```

Does anyone know how to get the checkboxes to work without getting this error each time both boxes are unchecked? Thanks in advance.

The complete code:

```
 <?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Fire valgfrie bilder', 'EKK-innstillinger', 'administrator', 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger', 'djj_fbpt_innstillinger', 'dashicons-admin-generic');
}

function djj_fbpt_innstillinger() {
    ?>
  <div class="wrap">
<h2>Fire valgfrie bilder</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">



    <?php

        function minevalg_hent_innstillinger() {
            $defaults = array(); // define this somewhere; reference it here
            return array_merge( $defaults, get_option( 'minevalg', array() ) );
        }
        $options = minevalg_hent_innstillinger();
    ?>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Skal bildene vises?</th>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="minevalg[valg_1]" value="1" <?php checked( $options['valg_1'], 1 ); ?> />
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Kun på forsiden?</th>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="minevalg[valg_2]" value="1" <?php checked( $options['valg_2'], 1 ); ?> />
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Bilde 1</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="bilde1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('bilde1') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Bilde 2</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="bilde2" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('bilde2') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Bilde 3</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="bilde3" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('bilde3') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Bilde 4</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="bilde4" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('bilde4') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_plugin_settings' );

function my_plugin_settings() {
    register_setting( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe', 'minevalg' );
    register_setting( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe', 'bilde1' );
    register_setting( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe', 'bilde2' );
    register_setting( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe', 'bilde3' );
    register_setting( 'djj-fbpt-innstillinger-gruppe', 'bilde4' );
}

$djj_minevalg;

function djj_fbpt_til_theme() {

    $djj_bilde1 = esc_attr( get_option('bilde1'));
    $djj_bilde2 = esc_attr( get_option('bilde2'));
    $djj_bilde3 = esc_attr( get_option('bilde3'));
    $djj_bilde4 = esc_attr( get_option('bilde4'));

    $djj_bilder['1'] = $djj_bilde1;
    $djj_bilder['2'] = $djj_bilde2;
    $djj_bilder['3'] = $djj_bilde3;
    $djj_bilder['4'] = $djj_bilde4;
    return $djj_bilder;
}

// funksjonen kjøres hvis fire bilder skal vises
$options = get_option( 'minevalg' );

if(isset( $options['valg_1'])) :
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'djj_firebilder_css_synlig' );
else : // ellers kjøres en css-fil som gjemmer bildene
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'djj_firebilder_css_usynlig' );
endif;

function djj_firebilder_css_synlig() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'firebilder', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/firebilder.css' );
}
function djj_firebilder_css_usynlig() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'firebilder', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/firebilder_skjult.css' );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure it's definitely an array before you try to merge it:

```
function minevalg_hent_innstillinger() {
    $defaults = array(); // define this somewhere; reference it here

    if ( is_array( $options = get_option( 'minevalg' ) ) )
        $options = array_merge( $defaults, $options );
    else
        $options = $defaults; 

    return $options;
}
```